# Generate a whole random variate uniformly distributed

Tags: random-variables, simulation

I have to describe an algorithm to generate a whole random variate $X$ uniformly distributed on the interval $[a,b]$ where $a,b\ge0, b>a$

I used the inverse trasform algorithm:

STEP1: 
Generate U $(0,1)$ random variable.

STEP2: 
The distribibution function of $X$ is:
$$F(X)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \space\space if \space\space x<a \\
(x-a)\div (b-a) \space\space if \space\space a\le x\le b \\
1 \space \space if \space \space x >b
\end{array}\right.$$
Set $F(X) = (X-a) \div (b-a)= U$

Solve for $X$ in terms of $U$ yields:

$X=a+(b-a) \times U $

STEP3:
If $X \in Z^+ $ stop, else go to STEP1.

Is it correct?

Comment: The trouble is that this algorithm never stops.

Comment: Oh...you are right. The pseudorandom U will always in (0,1). 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If I take just the whole part of a+(b-a)*U?

Comment: Great idea--which needs a slight tweaking since the integer part of a+(b-a)U is never b. But surely you will manage...

Comment: Maybe I can consider: `F(X)=X-a/(b+1-a)=U if a<x<b+1.` So I take the integer part of `X=a+(b+1-a)*U`

Comment: Indeed. This works for every integers a<=b.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your support.